# Error : Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: reactjs

I'm following the `reactjs` tutorial, and I keep running into an issue when
 **passing the value from the state of one component into another component**.

The error `Cannot read property 'map' of undefined'` 
is thrown when the `map` function in the `CommentList` component is executed.

> What would cause the `prop` to be `undefined` when passing from `CommentBox` into the `CommentList`?

```js
// First component
var CommentList = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var commentNodes = this.props.data.map(function (comment){
      return <div><h1>{comment.author}</h1></div>;
    });
    return <div className="commentList">{commentNodes}</div>;
  }
});
// Second component    
var CommentBox = React.createClass({
   getInitialState: function(){
     return {data: []};
   },
   getComments: function(){
      $.ajax({
        url: this.props.url,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){ this.setState({data: data}) }.bind(this),
        error: function(xhr, status, err){ console.error(url, status, err.toString()) }.bind(this)
      });
   },
   componentWillMount: function(){
      this.getComments()
   },
   render: function(){
      return <div className="commentBox">{<CommentList data={this.state.data.comments}/>}</div>;
   }
});

React.renderComponent( <CommentBox url="comments.json" />, document.getElementById('content'));
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Line 0: Parsing error: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62079477/line-0-parsing-error-cannot-read-property-map-of-undefined)

Answer (score 69, accepted):

First of all, set more safe initial data:

```
getInitialState : function() {
    return {data: {comments:[]}};
},
```

And ensure your ajax data.

It should work if you follow above two instructions like [Demo.](http://jsbin.com/hozamejo/1/edit)

Updated: you can just wrap the .map block with conditional statement.

```
if (this.props.data) {
  var commentNodes = this.props.data.map(function (comment){
      return (
        <div>
          <h1>{comment.author}</h1>
        </div>
      );
  });
}
```

Comment: This solution worked, but I'm curious. If I have a more complicated JSON structure, would I have to initialize the data object the same way? It seems like there should be a better way. Thanks

Comment: @Nael No, you don't need to. Just wrap the block like above. :)

Comment: The error occurs because `this.props.data` is null. `.map` expects to be called on an array.

Comment: @timothyclifford thanks for the answer. I understand `this.props.data` is null which caused the map function to fail. But what I don't understand is that the tutorial code works without the if clause. Why `this.props.data` is not null in the tutorial?

Comment: `this.props.data` is populated by the AJAX request. The AJAX is asynchronous so if the component is rendered before the data is populated, `this.props.data` will be null and you'll get the error. Does this make sense?

Comment: Hi @timothyclifford, can I implement this by using props and geting the josn from server side? I am new in React, I think the data will not change after initiated so I want use props to implement this. But the problem just like you say the props.data is NULL

Comment: Hi @MichaelMao would you like to post your question separately and show the code you have then we can help sort out any problems.

Comment: Hi @timothyclifford In the final, I use state to implement it and it works good now. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: This can also work,

```var commentNodes =  this.props.data && this.props.data.map(function (comment){
      return (
        <div>
          <h1>{comment.author}</h1>
        </div>
      );
  });```

Answer (score 14):

I think you forgot to change

```
data={this.props.data}
```

to

```
data={this.state.data}
```

in the render function of CommentBox. I did the same mistake when I was following the tutorial. Thus the whole render function should look like

```
render: function() {
  return (
    <div className="commentBox">
      <h1>Comments</h1>
      <CommentList data={this.state.data} />
      <CommentForm />
    </div>
  );
}
```

instead of

```
render: function() {
  return (
    <div className="commentBox">
      <h1>Comments</h1>
      <CommentList data={this.props.data} />
      <CommentForm />
    </div>
  );
```

Answer (score 11):

You need to put the data before render

Should be like this:

```
var data = [
  {author: "Pete Hunt", text: "This is one comment"},
  {author: "Jordan Walke", text: "This is *another* comment"}
];

React.render(
  <CommentBox data={data}/>,
  document.getElementById('content')
);
```

Instead of this:

```
React.render(
  <CommentBox data={data}/>,
  document.getElementById('content')
);

var data = [
  {author: "Pete Hunt", text: "This is one comment"},
  {author: "Jordan Walke", text: "This is *another* comment"}
];
```

Answer (score 7):

The error `"Cannot read property 'map' of undefined"` will be encountered if there is an error in the `"this.props.data"` or there is no props.data array.

Better put condition to check the the array like

```
if(this.props.data){
this.props.data.map(........)
.....
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I considered giving a comment under the answer by [taggon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33068942/10849438) to this very question, but well, i felt it owed more explanation for those interested in details.

> **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined** is strictly a JavaScript error.
>   
> *(Note that value can be anything, but for this question value is 'map')*

It's critical to understand that point, just so you avoid endless debugging cycles.
This error is common especially if just starting out in JavaScript (and it's libraries/frameworks).
 For `React`, this has a lot to do with understanding the [component lifecycle methods](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html).

```js
// Follow this example to get the context
// Ignore any complexity, focus on how 'props' are passed down to children

import React, { useEffect } from 'react'

// Main component
const ShowList = () => {
  // Similar to componentDidMount and componentDidUpdate
  useEffect(() => {// dispatch call to fetch items, populate the redux-store})

  return <div><MyItems items={movies} /></div>
}

// other component
const MyItems = props =>
  <ul>
    {props.items.map((item, i) => <li key={i}>item</li>)}
  </ul>


/**
  The above code should work fine, except for one problem.
  When compiling <ShowList/>,
  React-DOM renders <MyItems> before useEffect (or componentDid...) is called.
  And since `items={movies}`, 'props.items' is 'undefined' at that point.
  Thus the error message 'Cannot read property map of undefined'
 */
```

As a way to tackle this problem, @taggon gave a solution (see first anwser or link).

> **Solution**: Set an initial/default value.
>  In our example, we can avoid `items` being 'undefined' by declaring a `default` value of an empty array.
>   **Why?** This allows React-DOM to render an empty list initially.
> And when the `useEffect` or `componentDid...` method is executed, the component is re-rendered with a populated list of items.

```js
// Let's update our 'other' component
// destructure the `items` and initialize it as an array

const MyItems = ({items = []}) =>
  <ul>
    {items.map((item, i) => <li key={i}>item</li>)}
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is what my issue where:

```
{props.users.map((item,index)=>(
    <div className="items" key={index}>
        <div className="text-center">
            <p className="fs-12">{item}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
))}
```

And then i just fixed the issue with adding this code. It works just as if and else statement.

```
{ props.users ? props.users.map((item,index)=>(
        <div className="items" key={index}>
            <div className="text-center">
                <p className="fs-12">{item}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
)) : <p>Users is empty</p>}
```

Answer (score 2):

The error occur mainly becuase the array isnt found. Just check if you have mapped to the correct array. Check the array name or declaration.

Comment: Man i was missing a 's' in my arrayName i defined. I literally wasted 3 hours on it!

Comment: @JoeKevinRayan Glad it helped !

Answer (score 0):

in my case it happens when I try add types to Promise.all handler:

```
Promise.all([1,2]).then(([num1, num2]: [number, number])=> console.log('res', num1));
```

If remove  `: [number, number]`, the error is gone.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. if i use props.worktyp.map it throws me an error of map is not defined.

```
//App.js
    const worktyp = [
          "Full-time",
          "casual",
          "part-time",
          "contract"
        ];
    
    function Main(props){
      return(
    <section>
      <p>This the main body</p>
      <ul style = {{textAlign:"left"}}>
        **{worktyp.map((work) => <li>{work}</li>)}**
      </ul>
    </section>
    
      );
        }
 function App() {
      return (
        <div className="App">
          <Header name="initial"/>
          **<Main work={worktyp}/>**
          <Foot year ={new Date().getFullYear()}/>
        </div>
      );
    }
//index.js
    ReactDOM.render(
     <App />,
      document.getElementById('root')
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

react js when api call data
app: [{programname: "string", status: "duplicate"}]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In my case I solved this error by adding "?" condition.

### Before:

```
<div className="hotelContainer__img">
              {photos.map((item, index) => (
                <img
                  src={item}
                  alt=""
                  key={index}
                  onClick={() => handleOpen(index)}
                />
              ))}
            </div>
```

### After

```
<div className="hotelContainer__img">
              {photos?.map((item, index) => (
                <img
                  src={item}
                  alt=""
                  key={index}
                  onClick={() => handleOpen(index)}
                />
              ))}
            </div>
```