# Avoid cannot read property 'map' of undefined in react redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have see some answer like [Cannot read property 'map' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24706267/cannot-read-property-map-of-undefined) , but it is for react, not work in react-redux.

main code:

containers/TreeNode.js:

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react'
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import classNames from 'classnames/bind'
import * as NodeActions from '../actions/NodeActions'

export default class TreeNode extends Component {

  // getInitialState() {
  //     return {nodes:[]};
  // }

  // warning.js?8a56:45 Warning: getInitialState was defined on TreeNode, a plain JavaScript class. This is only supported for classes created using React.createClass. Did you mean to define a state property instead?

  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context)
    this.props = {
      open: false,
      nodes: [],
      info:{}
    }
  }

  handleClick() {
    this.setState({ open: !this.state.open })
    if (this.state.open){
      this.actions.getNodes()
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { actions, nodes, info } = this.props

    console.log(this.props)
    console.log(nodes===undefined)

    return (
      <div className={classNames('tree-node', { 'open':this.props.open})} onClick={ () => {this.handleClick()} }>
        <a>{info.name}</a>
        <div>{nodes.map(node => <TreeNode info={node} />)}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}


TreeNode.propTypes = {
  info:PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  nodes:PropTypes.array,
  actions: PropTypes.object.isRequired
}
```

`nodes.map` would throw error `cannot read property 'map' of undefined`, I know nodes maybe undefined.

I have tried

1. add getInitialState

   ```
   getInitialState() {
     return {nodes:[]};
   }
   ```

   Got: `warning.js?8a56:45 Warning: getInitialState was defined on TreeNode, a plain JavaScript class. This is only supported for classes created using React.createClass. Did you mean to define a state property instead?`

This is says getInitialState can not use in component.

2. change render to use if else:

   ```
    render() {
       const { actions, nodes, info } = this.props

       console.log(this.props)
       console.log(nodes===undefined)

       if (nodes) {
         const children =<div>{nodes.map(node => <TreeNode info={node} />)}</div>
       } else {
         const children = <div>no open</div>
       }

       return (
         <div className={classNames('tree-node', { 'open':this.props.open})} onClick={ () => {this.handleClick()} }>
           <a>{info.name}</a>
           { children }
         </div>
       );
     }
   ```

error change to : `children is undefined` ....confusing.

3. change if else condition to { ? :}

   ```
   const children = { nodes ? <div>{nodes.map(node => <TreeNode info={node} actions={actions} />)}</div> : <div>no open</div> }
   ```

   got syntax error:

   ```
   ERROR in ./src/containers/TreeNode.js
   Module build failed: SyntaxError: E:/Project/simple-redux-boilerplate/src/containers/TreeNode.js: Unexpected token (54:2
   9)
     52 |         // <div>{nodes.map(node => <TreeNode info={node} />)}</div>
     53 |
   > 54 |     const children = { nodes ? <div>{nodes.map(node => <TreeNode info={node} actions={actions} />)}</div> : <div>
   no open</div> }
        |                              ^
     55 |     return (
     56 |       <div className={classNames('tree-node', { 'open':this.props.open})} onClick={ () => {this.handleClick()} }>
   ```

And finally 
4. I see some code like below in an example:

```
    {!user &&
    <div>
      <p>This will "log you in" as this user, storing the username in the session of the API server.</p>
    </div>
    }
    {user &&
    <div>
      <p>You are currently logged in as {user.name}.</p>
    </div>
    }
```

so I tried to use:

```
{nodes && <div>{nodes.map(node => <TreeNode info={node} />)}</div>
}
```

This worked , but I don't know why ..

I have a look into [if-else-in-JSX](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/if-else-in-JSX.html), nothing related to above.

I just want to know why 2, 3 don't work, and what is the syntax 4 used, any doc?

Comment: By the way if you want to initialize the state in a component class, you just need to initialize it in constructor : `constructor(props) { ..., this.state = {your_state}}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I just want to know why 2, 3 don't work

2 doesn't work because `const`s are **block-scoped**. I.e. `children` is only accessible inside the `if` and `else` blocks. Simplified example:

```
if (true) {
  const foo = 42;
  // foo is only visible inside this {...}
}
console.log(foo); // error
```

3 doesn't work because you are using `{...}` in a way they are not supposed to be used. `{...}` are either a block or an object literal or mark an expression if used inside JSX. You are using them on the RHS of an assignment, so they are interpreted as *object literal*. The contents of `{...}` is not valid for an object literal though, hence you get a syntax error.

The why you wanted to use them only works inside JSX. Outside JSX you don't need them. This works fine:

```
const children = nodes ? <div>{nodes.map(node => <TreeNode info={node} actions={actions} />)}</div> : <div>no open</div>;
```

> what is the syntax 4 used, any doc?

`&&` is the *logical AND* operator. This way works because logical AND and OR return the last evaluated value of the expression. In in your case, if `nodes` in array, it converts to `true`, which means the right operand (`<div>...</div>`) has to be evaluated as well.
But if `nodes` is `undefined` (converts to `false`), the right operand is *not* evaluated.

[Read more about logical operators on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) and about [short circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

Some examples:

```
'' && 42    // ''
'foo' && 42 // 42

'' || 42    // 42
'foo' || 42 // 'foo'
```

Comment: I have never use `&&` to return last value, always use in condition. Learn new knowledge, Thanks~