# Array.prototype.map returns undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am trying to render an array as a collection of `<li>` elements. I am using React with ES2015 syntax and Babel for translation.

The array is stored in an object and can be accessed as `this.props.technologies`, so when I write this:

```
<ul className="categories">
    { this.props.technologies }
</ul>
```

I get the following html output:

```
<ul class="categories" is="null">
    coffeescript
    atom
</ul>
```

But, when I try this:

```
<ul className="categories">
{
  this.props.technologies.map(c => {
    return `<li>${c}</li>`
  })
}
```

I get an error saying : `this.props.technologies is undefined`

I even tried doing this:

```
this.props.technologies.map(c => c)
```

just to check if map is working, but it still results in the same error.

**Edit**

I tried testing it, and found that it occurs only when I fetch data using AJAX.

**Edit 2**
I am providing an MVCE

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'

class Header extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  this.state = {}
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <ul>
      {
        this.props.technologies.map(c => <li>{c}</li>)
      }
      </ul>
    )
  }
}

class Details extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state={}
  }

  componentWillMount(){
    axios.get(`/static/dummydata/test.json`)
      .then(res => this.setState(res.data))
      .catch(res=>console.log(res))
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <Header technologies={this.state.technologies}/>
    )
  }
}

export {Header, Details}
```

The data in test.json is:

```
{
  "technologies": [
    "coffeescript",
    "js"
  ]
}
```

Comment: can you share the total coe u written

Comment: it could be that `this.props.technologies` is not an array in your example

Comment: Maybe check if technologies is really array or array-like object. You can do it for example by `Array.isArray(this.props.technologies)`.

Comment: @yariash @anvk `Array.isArray(this.props.technologies)` returns true

Comment: @ShubhamKumaram provide [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) then

Comment: can you console out the "this.props" value where you declare the map function. My guess is that either you have overwritten this.props, or the this binding is lost where you are using it.

Comment: @jamesemanon Yes, I can see it in the console.

Comment: I just found out, it only occurs when I fetch data using AJAX, but not when the data is hard coded in the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it to work. The problem in my code occurred only when I fetched data via AJAX, so it may have happened that the `technologies` property didn't exist when the function was first called. The solution that worked for me was to create an empty `technologies` array in the state object in the constructor.

The modified constructor of `Details` class:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  this.state={
    "technologies": []
  }
}
```

I believe this question has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24706849/6448652), but I was unable to find it due to a different error message in Firefox. I hope this answer helps someone in a similar situation.

Answer (score 0):

the problem has nothing to do with map.  this.props doesn't have the property "technologies".  Look at whatever code is supposed to assign the technologies array to this.props (I'm not familiar with react).

Comment: the technologies property is there, since the first code snippet runs fine

Comment: It looks like you've checked and are sure that it is an array. and that it does exist.  The only other thing that I can think is that it doesn't exist at the time when you are calling it.  Maybe you're calling map when this.props doesn't have a technology property.