# Cannot read property 'map' of undefined reactjs

Tags: reactjs, npm

I am using fabric-react commandBar component with the same code given here:
[fabric-ui-commandbar](https://dev.office.com/fabric#/components/commandbar)

but i am getting following error at run-time.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
```

And my code is as follows:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { assign } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/Utilities';
import { CommandBar } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/CommandBar';
import { Toggle } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/Toggle';

export class MyPage extends React.Component<any, any> {

  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isSearchBoxVisible: true,
      areNamesVisible: true,
      areIconsVisible: true
    };
  }

  public render() {
    let { items, farItems } = this.props;
    let { isSearchBoxVisible: searchBoxVisible, areIconsVisible: iconsVisible, areNamesVisible: namesVisible } = this.state;

    let filteredItems = items.map(item => assign({}, item, {
      name: namesVisible ? item.name : '',
      icon: iconsVisible ? item.icon : ''
    }));

    let filteredFarItems = farItems.map(item => assign({}, item, {
      name: namesVisible ? item.name : '',
      icon: iconsVisible ? item.icon : ''
    }));

    return (
      <div>
        <Toggle
          label='Show search box'
          checked={ searchBoxVisible }
          onChanged={ isSearchBoxVisible => this.setState({ isSearchBoxVisible }) }
          onText='Visible'
          offText='Hidden'
        />
        <Toggle
          label='Show names'
          checked={ namesVisible }
          onChanged={ areNamesVisible => this.setState({ areNamesVisible }) }
          onText='Visible'
          offText='Hidden' />
        <Toggle
          label='Show icons'
          checked={ iconsVisible }
          onChanged={ areIconsVisible => this.setState({ areIconsVisible }) }
          onText='Visible'
          offText='Hidden' />
        <CommandBar
          isSearchBoxVisible={ searchBoxVisible }
          searchPlaceholderText='Search...'
          elipisisAriaLabel='More options'
          items={ filteredItems }
          farItems={ filteredFarItems }
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Please help me what is the problem with this?
I have installed  **Fabric React NPM package**.

Comment: The items and farItems are coming in the props from a parent component. Where is it?

Comment: it can be in assign component. I dont know more about this and react too

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot read property 'map' of undefined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24706267/cannot-read-property-map-of-undefined)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is that your props `items` and `farItems` are not arrays. This could be because they are genuinely not arrays, or that when the component first loads the data hasn't been loaded yet, so the props are undefined.

A simple fix to the data having not loaded is to provide defaults for these props. Try something like `let { items = [], farItems = [] } = this.props;` inside your render method.

Comment: i tried this but it gives me nothing. An error is removed.