# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
var axios = require('axios');
class Application extends React.Component {        
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);        
    this.state = {
      dropdownItems: []
    };
  }        
  deleteDd(index) {
    let dropdownItems =  this.state.dropdownItems.filter(item => item!==index);
    this.setState({dropdownItems: dropdownItems});
  }        
  handleClick() {
    let dropdownItems = [...this.state.dropdownItems];
    dropdownItems.push(dropdownItems.length);
    this.setState({dropdownItems: dropdownItems});
  }        
getInitialState() {
    return {
      company: []
    }
  }
//trying to get json data into dropdown by passing the json object into the url         
  componentDidMount(){var _this = this;
    this.serverRequest = axios

        .get("myurl")
        .then(function(result) {    
          _this.setState({
            company: result.data.company        
          });
          //console.log(jobs);
        })
  }        
  componentWillUnmount(){
    this.serverRequest.abort();
  }
  render() {
    let dropdowns = this.state.dropdownItems.map(item =>
      (<MyDropdown key = {item} num = {item} onDeleteMe ={this.deleteDd.bind(this, item)} />));        
    return (
    <div>
    <h1 className="text-left page-title">Higher</h1>
    <h2 className="text-left">CTR</h2>
    <h3 className="text-left">ABC</h3>            
    <div>       
            <form>
    <select className="dropdown menu dropdown-style" data-dropdown-menu>
                        <option defaultValue>Choose one</option>
                        <option value="test">test</option>
                        <option value="test1">test1</option>               
                    </select>
      //here is where all my json data resides in company              
        <h1>Companies!</h1>
        {this.state.company.map(function(company) {
          return (
            <div key={company.id} className="company">                      
                {company.Company}      
                                 </div>);})}
            </form>
```

I am getting this error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined" I am trying to load json data into a dropdown please help. I have tried all the possible ways i can but still not able to figure what the problem is, any help is very much appreciated thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot read property 'map' of undefined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24706267/cannot-read-property-map-of-undefined)

Comment: Possibly `this.state.company` is undefined when you are trying to map, because it is being populated asynchronously. Just put a check whether the`this.state.company` is undefined or not. Try `this.state.company && this.state.company.map.....`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you extend React.Component to create a React component then getInitialState does not initialise the state variable. You need to do it in `constructor`. Hnece when you initialise `company` as an empty array to state with `getInitialState()`, it did not set it and hence initially `this.state.company` is undefined.

Initialise the state in constructor and it should be fine. Also to avoid any problems you can perform a check for undefined before mapping like `{this.state.company && this.state.company.map(function(company) {...})}`

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
var axios = require('axios');
class Application extends React.Component {        
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);        
    this.state = {
      dropdownItems: [],
      company: []
    };
  }        
  deleteDd(index) {
    let dropdownItems =  this.state.dropdownItems.filter(item => item!==index);
    this.setState({dropdownItems: dropdownItems});
  }        
  handleClick() {
    let dropdownItems = [...this.state.dropdownItems];
    dropdownItems.push(dropdownItems.length);
    this.setState({dropdownItems: dropdownItems});
  }        

//trying to get json data into dropdown by passing the json object into the url         
  componentDidMount(){var _this = this;
    this.serverRequest = axios

        .get("myurl")
        .then(function(result) {    
          _this.setState({
            company: result.data.company        
          });
          //console.log(jobs);
        })
  }        
  componentWillUnmount(){
    this.serverRequest.abort();
  }
  render() {
    let dropdowns = this.state.dropdownItems.map(item =>
      (<MyDropdown key = {item} num = {item} onDeleteMe ={this.deleteDd.bind(this, item)} />));        
    return (
    <div>
    <h1 className="text-left page-title">Higher</h1>
    <h2 className="text-left">CTR</h2>
    <h3 className="text-left">ABC</h3>            
    <div>       
            <form>
    <select className="dropdown menu dropdown-style" data-dropdown-menu>
                        <option defaultValue>Choose one</option>
                        <option value="test">test</option>
                        <option value="test1">test1</option>               
                    </select>
      //here is where all my json data resides in company              
        <h1>Companies!</h1>
        {this.state.company && this.state.company.map(function(company) {
          return (
            <div key={company.id} className="company">                      
                {company.Company}      
                                 </div>);})}
            </form>
```