# How to fix the error TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The error is given in my map function.

I'm following a `reactjs` tutorial, and I keep running into an issue when passing the value from the state of one component into another component.
I am connecting to back end with `axios.get()`.

```
export default class Viewcustomer extends React.Component{

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      Id:"",
      name:"",
      fax:"",    
      NIC: "",
      type: "",
      email: "",
      website: "",
      address: "",
      phoneNo: "",
      DOB: "",
      note: "",
      customer:[]  
    }    
  }

  onChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({[e.target.name]: e.target.value})
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get(`http://localhost:5001/customer/view`)
      .then(res => {
         const customers = res.data;
         this.setState({ customers });
      })
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <table width="100%">
        <tr>
          <th>Id</th>
          <th>name</th>
          <th>fax</th>
          <th>NIC</th>
          <th>type</th>
          <th>email</th>
          <th>address</th>
          <th>phoneNo</th>
          <th>DOB</th>
          <th>note</th>

        </tr>
        //Error raised by this line of code
        { this.state.customers.map(customer =>
          <tr>
            <td>{customer.Id}</td>
            <td>{customer.name}</td>
            <td>{customer.fax}</td>
            <td>{customer.NIC}</td>
            <td>{customer.type}</td>
            <td>{customer.email}</td>
            <td>{customer.address}</td>
            <td>{customer.phoneNo}</td>
            <td>{customer.DOB}</td>
            <td>{customer.note}</td>
          </tr>)}
      </table>
    )
  }
}
```

[Image of the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B4V6K.png)

**Edit**

Error relates to the line marked with the quote, issue raised by the map() function, however the underlying issue is the `this.state.customers` is `undefined`.

Comment: In your declaration of `this.state` you made a typo, `customer` should be `customers`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot read property 'map' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24706267/cannot-read-property-map-of-undefined)

Answer (score 1):

```
this.state.customers.map(...
```

The problem is that `this.state.customers` is set when the component mounts, and only after an asynchronous call with axios returns. That means that when the component is first rendered, `this.state.customers` will not have been set yet.

**Posible solution**

Either check if `this.state.customers` exists before using it, or maybe just initialize it as an empty array. I noticed that you're initializing a `customer` (singular) as an empty array, is that a typo?

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
        Id:"",
        name:"",
        fax:"",    
        NIC: "",
        type: "",
        email: "",
        website: "",
        address: "",
        phoneNo: "",
        DOB: "",
        note: "",
        customers:[] // initialize customers, this.state.customers is now defined
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you should know is that `componentDidMount` runs after render method. So in the first render your `customer` parameter is still `[]` and even you write a simple `console.log()` in `componentDidMount` it runs after render method.

You can understand what is happening by running the code below:

```
    class Test extends React.Component {
        constructor(props){
           console.log('constructor')
        }
        render(){
          console.log('render')
        }
        componentDidMount(){
          console.log('componentDidMount')
        }
    }
```

The result will be like this:

constructor

render

componentDidMount

But for solving your problem you should show a spinner or something like this in the time that you are waiting to receive your response from axios. and your component could be like this:

```
export default class Viewcustomer extends React.Component{

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      Id:"",
      name:"",
      fax:"",    
      NIC: "",
      type: "",
      email: "",
      website: "",
      address: "",
      phoneNo: "",
      DOB: "",
      note: "",
      customer:[]  
    }    
  }

  onChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({[e.target.name]: e.target.value})
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get(`http://localhost:5001/customer/view`)
      .then(res => {
         const customers = res.data;
         this.setState({ customers });
      })
  }

  render(){
    if(this.state.customers.length===0){
    return(
     <div>Loading...</div>
    )
    }
    else{
    return(
      <table width="100%">
        <tr>
          <th>Id</th>
          <th>name</th>
          <th>fax</th>
          <th>NIC</th>
          <th>type</th>
          <th>email</th>
          <th>address</th>
          <th>phoneNo</th>
          <th>DOB</th>
          <th>note</th>

        </tr>
        //Error raised by this line of code
        { this.state.customers.map(customer =>
          <tr>
            <td>{customer.Id}</td>
            <td>{customer.name}</td>
            <td>{customer.fax}</td>
            <td>{customer.NIC}</td>
            <td>{customer.type}</td>
            <td>{customer.email}</td>
            <td>{customer.address}</td>
            <td>{customer.phoneNo}</td>
            <td>{customer.DOB}</td>
            <td>{customer.note}</td>
          </tr>)}
      </table>
    )
    }
  }
}
```

Please vote me up if it was helpful:)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that in the usage you're using `this.state.costumers` and your define state is `customer`.

```
export default class Viewcustomer extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            Id: "",
            name: "",
            fax: "",
            NIC: "",
            type: "",
            email: "",
            website: "",
            address: "",
            phoneNo: "",
            DOB: "",
            note: "",
            customers: []


        }

    }

    onChange = (e) => {
        this.setState(
            { [e.target.name]: e.target.value }
        )
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get(`http://localhost:5001/customer/view`)
            .then(res => {
                const customers = res.data;
                this.setState({ customers });
            })
    }


    render() {
        const { costumers } = this.state:
        return (
            <table width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <th>Id</th>
                    <th>name</th>
                    <th>fax</th>
                    <th>NIC</th>
                    <th>type</th>
                    <th>email</th>
                    <th>address</th>
                    <th>phoneNo</th>
                    <th>DOB</th>
                    <th>note</th>

                </tr>
                {customers.map(customer =>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{customer.Id}</td>
                        <td>{customer.name}</td>
                        <td>{customer.fax}</td>
                        <td>{customer.NIC}</td>
                        <td>{customer.type}</td>
                        <td>{customer.email}</td>
                        <td>{customer.address}</td>
                        <td>{customer.phoneNo}</td>
                        <td>{customer.DOB}</td>

                        <td>{customer.note}</td>
                    </tr>)}
            </table>


        )
    }
}
```

That's the whole problem because when you initialize the `costumers` state as an empty Array, the `map` method will stop failing. Hope this helps. Best Regards.

Comment: Thank you It helps to fix. Thank you for your explanation.

Comment: Could you vote for my answer if it helps you? Regards. @ChehaniLakshika

Answer (score 0):

As noted in other answers `this.state.customers` is `undefined` throwing the error. This is because initially in the constructor you are initialising `customer` singular and not `customers`, quick change should fix this.

Can I recommend since you are looking at tutorials, [React Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) are a really powerful and intuitive way of using "stateless" (they do still hold a state) functional components instead of class components. They simplify the coding of components massively and make handling state far easier.