# React-Admin: Using "getList", I am getting "Error: cannot read property 'map' of undefined"

Tags: node.js, rest, api, react-admin

With `react-admin`, i'm trying to get the users list from API Restful Node server,
and I have this error:

```js
Error: cannot read property 'map' of undefined
```

Here's the getUsers in server `user.controller.js`:

```js
const getUsers = catchAsync(async (req, res) => {
  const users = await userService.getUsers(req.query);
  const data = users.map(user => user.transform());
  const total = users.length;

  res.type('json');
  res.set('Access-Control-Expose-Headers', 'Content-Range');
  res.set('Content-Range', `users 0-2/${total}`);
  res.set('X-Total-Count', total);
  response = '{ data: ' + JSON.stringify(data) + ', total: ' + total + ' }';
  res.send(response);
});
```

Here the data `response` received:

```js
{
 data: [
 {"id":"5e6f5e3b4cf60a67701deeae","email":"admin@test.com","firstname":"Ad","lastname":"Min","role":"admin"},
 {"id":"5e6f5e3b4cf60a67701deeaf","email":"test@test.com","firstname":"Jhon","lastname":"Doe","role":"user"}
 ],
 total: 2 
}
```

In `react-admin`, `getList` in `dataProvider.js`:

```js
export default {
  getList: (resource, params) => {
    console.log(params);
    const { field, order } = params.sort;
    const query = {
      ...fetchUtils.flattenObject(params.filter),
      sortBy: field
    };
    const url = `${apiUrl}/${resource}?${stringify(query)}`;
    return httpClient(url).then(({ headers }, json) => ({
      data: json,
      total: parseInt(
        headers
          .get("Content-Range")
          .split("/")
          .pop(),
        10
      )
    }));
  },
```

Update:
UserList.tsx

```
import React from "react";
import {
  TextField,
  Datagrid,
  DateInput,
  Filter,
  List,
  EmailField,
  SearchInput
} from "react-admin";
import { useMediaQuery, Theme } from "@material-ui/core";
import SegmentInput from "./SegmentInput";
import MobileGrid from "./MobileGrid";

const UserFilter = (props: any) => (
  <Filter {...props}>
    <SearchInput source="q" alwaysOn />
    <DateInput source="createdAt" />
    <SegmentInput />
  </Filter>
);

const UserList = (props: any) => {
  const isXsmall = useMediaQuery<Theme>(theme => theme.breakpoints.down("xs"));
  return (
    <List
      {...props}
      filters={<UserFilter />}
      sort={{ field: "createdAt", order: "desc" }}
      perPage={25}
    >
      {isXsmall ? (
        <MobileGrid />
      ) : (
        <Datagrid optimized rowClick="edit">
          <TextField source="id" />
          <EmailField source="email" />
          <TextField source="firstname" />
          <TextField source="lastname" />
          <TextField source="role" />
          <DateInput source="createdAt" />
          <DateInput source="updatedAt" />
        </Datagrid>
      )}
    </List>
  );
};

export default UserList;
```

Here the documentation with somes examples for getList:
https://marmelab.com/react-admin/DataProviders.html#writing-your-own-data-provider

I don't understand, i need help please, what wrong?

Thanks & Regards
Ludo

Comment: Could you kindly provide the code snippet for where you are rendering this `<List>` component at the client-side? I suspect the problem is within there.

Comment: Ok, problem might be originating from this line `const data = users.map(user => user.transform());`. At some point, `users` is undefined. See answer below.

Answer (score 0):

> Here's a [detailed explanation of what's happening](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58691066/10849438) with the `map()` in `reactjs`.
>
> And [this source is on point for resolving](https://medium.com/@antonioval/making-array-iteration-easy-when-using-async-await-6315c3225838) this in `nodejs`

In your case, let's take a closer look here:

```js
// user.controller.js

const getUsers = catchAsync(async (req, res) => {
  // Actually, it might be wiser to first declare users
+ let users = [];

  // You await for users (querying) to be resolved or rejected, cool
- const users = await userService.getUsers(req.query);

  // And we then we assign "users" as before
+ users = await userService.getUsers(req.query);

  // But here, map() requires users to be defined before iteration.
  // So for this to work, we need the value of users to be resolved first, right?
- const data = users.map(user => user.transform());
  
  // Could you change the above line to this, and see?
  // This doesn't because we gave map(), a synchronous parameter (function)
- const data = Promise.all(users.map(user => user.transform()));
  
  // Ok, break this up for easier understanding
  // let's declare a userList, where we give map() an "async" parameter
  // At this point, userList will be an "Array of Promises"
+ const userList = users.map(async user => user.transform());
  
  // Now we resolve all the Promises, and we should have our clean data
+ const data = await Promise.all(userList);
});
```

With that change, we make sure that `map()` runs after our `users` is resolved.

Does that work for you? Let me know.

Comment: Thanks you for the edit. That doesn't work with that change, i get the same error and the data response is ```{ data: {}, total: 2 }```

Comment: Try the latest changes. That should sort our challenge. And if possible, kindly share the kind of errors you get in case they are different from the original error. Thanks.

Comment: I tried with the latest changes, (i also added createdAt and updatedAt that was missing in the user model...), i get the same error, and data response: `{ data: [{"id":"5e71fba1c259111c00f847c0","email":"admin@test.com","firstname":"Ad","lastname":"Min","role":"admin","createdAt":"2020-03-18T10:44:49.393Z","updatedAt":"2020-03-18T10:44:49.393Z"},{"id":"5e71fba1c259111c00f847c1","email":"test@test.com","firstname":"Jhon","lastname":"Doe","role":"user","createdAt":"2020-03-18T10:44:49.411Z","updatedAt":"2020-03-18T10:44:49.411Z"}], total: 2 }`

Comment: OK, at least there is progress. So looks like this server-side (`nodejs`) is now fine, right? Oh, i realize there is `user.transform()`. We might have to troubleshoot there too. Let me revert.

Comment: See that new update, it might be wiser to initialize "users" since we dealing with non-blocking code (asynchronous), `let users = [];`

Comment: With the new update i get the same error, and the data response seems good: `{ data: [{"id":"5e71fba1c259111c00f847c0","email":"admin@test.com","firstname":"Ad","lastname":"Min","role":"admin","createdAt":"2020-03-18T10:44:49.393Z","updatedAt":"2020-03-18T10:44:49.393Z"},{"id":"5e71fba1c259111c00f847c1","email":"test@test.com","firstname":"Jhon","lastname":"Doe","role":"user","createdAt":"2020-03-18T10:44:49.411Z","updatedAt":"2020-03-18T10:44:49.411Z"}], total: 2 }` I don't understand.

Comment: Ok, I now suspect we have to inlclude `await` within here: `const userList = users.map(async user => await user.transform());`.

Comment: This should be a challenge between the `node` server and `dataProvider`. Could you kindly share a [code snippet in a gist](https://gist.github.com/discover) or whatever you prefer so that I could take a closer look? `map()` being called before it's ready.

Comment: Like this? https://gist.github.com/lud-o/16f0020352d711a116a2d7d3ca718762

Comment: Yep, that's great. Will review and revert. Please add the `utils/catchAsync` file since you use it everywhere.