# React: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined with conditional statement

Tags: javascript, reactjs

guys hope everyine is doing well. So I am new to React and attempting to create a Stock APP. This component fetches the stock data for a stock I select from my Stocklist( another component) . I'm using a custom hook and it's functioning properly, but I am getting the cannot read property 'map' of undefined . The Json I am expecting has two arrays , detailed and aggregated and each array contains objects with a date property and a price property. I am attempting to map that data so that I can produce it into a graph.

The problem is the map function is executing before I select this activeStock, so it's trying to map a property of null, even though I put it in a conditional statement so it shouldn't execute

```
    import React from 'react';
    import Highcharts from 'highcharts'
    import HighchartsReact from 'highcharts-react-official'
    import useFetch, { DEFAULT_OPTIONS } from '../shared/useFetch';

   const StockGraph = (props) => {
const activeStock = props.activeStock

const string = "stocks/"
const activeURL = string.concat(activeStock, "/price/today")
console.log(activeURL)

const [stocks, isLoading, error] = useFetch(activeURL, DEFAULT_OPTIONS);

if (error) {
    return <div>`Error: {error}`</div>;
} else if (isLoading) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
} else if (stocks != null ) {
    const stockdetails= stocks.detailed
    const detailed = stockdetails.map((item) => {
        return {
            x: new Date(item.date),
            y: item.price
        };
    });
    const stocksaggr= stocks.aggregated
    const aggregated = stocks.aggregated.map((item) => {
        return {
            x: new Date(item.date),
            y: item.price
        };
    });
    const options = {
        chart: {
            type: 'line'
        },
        title: {
            text: activeStock
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: ''
        },
        xAxis: { type: 'datetime' },
        plotOptions: {
            line: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                enableMouseTracking: false
            }
        },
        series: [
            {
                name: 'detailed',
                data: detailed
            }
            ,
            {
                name: 'aggregated',
                data: aggregated
            }
        ]
    };
    console.log('graph-render', stocks)

    return (
        <section className='stock-graph'>
            <div id="stockGraphContainer" className="stock-graph__container">
                <HighchartsReact
                    highcharts={Highcharts}
                    options={options}
                />
            </div>
        </section>
    )

}
else {
    return null;
}
```

}

export default StockGraph;

Comment: Without a traceback we can't help you.

Comment: It appears that, although `stocks` isn't `null`, `stocks.detailed` is. Can't say any more without knowing what's in `stocks`

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Cannot read property 'map' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24706849/2873538).

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like `stocks.detailed` or `stocks.aggregated` itself is `undefined`. You need to add either add another conditional statement to check for that before executing the `map`. Or, maybe it shows another underlying problem with your code - should `stocks.aggregated`/`detailed` be defined at that point? If so, why isn't it? I can't tell you from what information you've given, unfortunately.

Comment: The problem is my map function shouldn't even be executed since stocks start out as being null

Comment: Well, it _is_ being executed, so at some point it isn't null. That's not the problem here though; `stocks.detailed` (or `.aggregated`) is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

Like what others said, your conditional is only checking if `stocks` is null. `stocks.detailed` or `stocks.aggregated` is what is being mapped so check if those values even exist. Double check if your `useFetch()` hook is really working as expected and getting the values you need. Throw logs at key points and you'll get closer to pinpointing what is going on.