# What is the right construction to print this JSON data in React?

Tags: json, reactjs, jsx, monday.com

I'm new to React language and running into problem involving printing out of a given object/data-structure.

Data structure (JSON?)

```
{ "boards": [ { "groups": [ { "title": "Introduction" }, { "title": "Page Two" } ] } ] }
```

I'm at the point that I can print `this.state.boardData.boards` I found some topics about the `map()` functionalities but can't seem to get this to work.

My compentDidMount (involving the monday.api and GraphQL):

```
  monday.listen("context", res => {
    this.setState({context: res.data});
    monday.api(`query ($boardIds: [Int]) { boards (ids:$boardIds) { groups { title } } }`, 
      { variables: {boardIds: this.state.context.boardIds} }
    )
    .then(res => {
      this.setState({boardData: res.data});
    });
    
  })
```

My map() function:

```
const navItems = this.state.boardData.boards.map((title) =>
  <a className="pageview__nav-item">{JSON.stringify(title, null, 2)}</a>
);
```

Provided error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
```

I'm guessing this is because the values are empty when I'm trying to map the values. I tried to initialize the data but without luck:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    
        // Default state
        this.state = {
          settings: {},
          name: "",
          boardData: {groups: []}
        };
      }
```

I also tried to initialize the variable but that seems to complaining about variables already being declared.

Anyone can point me into the right direction? That would be really helpful.

Comment: I found this question/answer but can really integrate it into my own scenario.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24706267/cannot-read-property-map-of-undefined

Comment: I think you can check if the object is undefined (or null, empty) before the map(). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27509/detecting-an-undefined-object-property This will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to do the map before the boardData is updated.

because of this:

constructor(props) {
super(props);

```
    // Default state
    this.state = {
      settings: {},
      name: "",
      boardData: {groups: []}
    };
  }
```

In your code:

```
const navItems = this.state.boardData.boards.map((title) =>
  <a className="pageview__nav-item">{JSON.stringify(title, null, 2)}</a>
);
```

`this.state.boardData.boards` doesn't exists and you get the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
```

Inside de return of the render you could do a validation before the use of the map so you make sure that array have values.

Following your JSON example data:

```
{ "boards": [ { "groups": [ { "title": "Introduction" }, { "title": "Page Two" } ] } ] }
```

You will need a map for each board an another map for each group inside the board to access to the titles

```
return(
    <>
    {this.state.boardData.boards ? this.state.boardData.boards.map((group) =>
          <div className="groupContainer">
          {
            group.map(title=>
              <a className="pageview__nav-item">{title}</a>
            )
          }
          </div>
          }): null}
    </>
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your option, I will try this out later in the evening, is it also possible to do this without the "double" mapping?

Comment: Yes! If you receive only the array of groups instead the boards array.