# Mapping from JSON Get Request. Undefined

Tags: json, reactjs, jsx, usda-fooddata-central-api

I am trying to connect to the USDA Food Central database using an API.

```
let uri = encodeURI(`https://api.nal.usda.gov/fdc/v1/foods/search?api_key=${MY_API_KEY}&query=${search}`)
```

I want to use the API to map certain fields.

```
class AddFoodItemList extends Component {
  static contextType = AddFoodContext;
  render() {
    const listItems = this.context.FoodSearch.map((foods) =>
      <FoodItem
        key={foods.brandOwner}
        brandOwner={foods.brandOwner}
        fdcId={foods.fdcId}
      />
    );

    return (
      <div id="AddFoodItemList">
        {listItems}
      </div>
    );
  }

}

export default AddFoodItemList;
```

The returned JSON is this screenshot attached:
[Returned JSON](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9IJ6t.png)

I am getting an error, TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined.
Why do you think this is the case? Any sort of help or suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: This means that your context does not have a property `FoodSearch` or the property `FoodSearch` has the value `undefined`.  I cannot debug this without seeing how you are passing a value to the context provider.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot read property 'map' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24706267/cannot-read-property-map-of-undefined)

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to access a property `FoodSearch` on the value of your `AddFoodContext` provider.  The error tells you that this property is `undefined`.  If the `object` in your screenshot is the `value` of your context then you want to access the property `foods` instead.  This is an `array` whose elements are objects with properties `brandOwner` and `fdcId`.

On your first render this data might now be loaded yet, so you should default to an empty array if `foods` is `undefined`.

It's honestly been a long time since I've used contexts in class components the way that you are doing it.  The style of code is very dated.  How about using the `useContext` hook to access the value?

```
const AddFoodItemList = () => {
  const contextValue = useContext(AddFoodContext);
  console.log(contextValue);

  const listItems = (contextValue.foods || []).map((foods) => (
    <FoodItem
      key={foods.fdcId} // brandOwner isn't unique
      brandOwner={foods.brandOwner}
      fdcId={foods.fdcId}
    />
  ));

  return <div id="AddFoodItemList">{listItems}</div>;
};
```

Here's a complete code to play with - [Code Sandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/usda-foodcentral-api-9nlmb?file=/src/App.jsx)

```
const MY_API_KEY = "DEMO_KEY"; // can replace with your actual key

const getUri = (search) => `https://api.nal.usda.gov/fdc/v1/foods/search?api_key=${MY_API_KEY}&query=${encodeURIComponent(search)}`;

const AddFoodContext = createContext({});

const FoodItem = ({ brandOwner, fdcId }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <span>{fdcId}</span> - <span>{brandOwner}</span>
    </div>
  );
};

const AddFoodItemList = () => {
  const contextValue = useContext(AddFoodContext);
  console.log(contextValue);

  const listItems = (contextValue.foods || []).map((foods) => (
    <FoodItem
      key={foods.fdcId} // brandOwner isn't unique
      brandOwner={foods.brandOwner}
      fdcId={foods.fdcId}
    />
  ));

  return <div id="AddFoodItemList">{listItems}</div>;
};

export default () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(getUri("cheese"))
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then(setData)
      .catch(console.error);
  }, []);

  return (
    <AddFoodContext.Provider value={data}>
      <AddFoodItemList />
    </AddFoodContext.Provider>
  );
};
```