# React Typescript: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, create-react-app

I am trying to map a card component with user data which I get from the jsonplaceholder using axios. However, when I tried, it returns with "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')". I tried all the solutions on the web without success.
Please help!

Here is the code that declared 'users';

```
export const useAllUsers = () => {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState<Array<User>>()
  const getUsers = useCallback(() => {
    axios
      .get<Array<User>>('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
      .then(res => {
        setUsers(res.data)})
         .catch(() => {
           return <MessageError />
         })
         .finally(()=>{
           setLoading(false)
         })
  }, [])
  return { getUsers, loading, users }
}
```

Then, I tried to map the 'users' get the all the user data as below:

```
export const UserManagement: VFC = memo(() => {
  const { getUsers, users, loading } = useAllUsers()
  useEffect(() => getUsers(), [])

  return (
    <>
      {loading ? (
        <div className=' flex justify-center items-center'>
          <div className='animate-spin rounded-full h-32 w-32 border-b-2 border-gray-900'></div>
        </div>
      ) : (
        <div
          className='grid 
        grid-cols-2 mb-16 md:grid-cols-3 lg:grid-cols-4 sm:px-6 md:px-16'
        > 
           <div className='grid mx-auto'> 
            {users.map(user => (
              <UserCard
                key={user.id}
                userName={user.username}
                imageUrl='https://source.unsplash.com/random'
                userId={user.name}
              />
            ))}
          </div> 
        </div> 
       )} 
    </>
  )
})
```

User type is just having a bunch of types for user data, so I think this is not the problem, I guess?

```
export type User = {
  id: number
  name: string
  username: string
  email: string
  hobbies: string
}
```

Comment: Change to this: `const [users, setUsers] = useState<Array<User>>([])` so the initial state is an empty array rather than undefined.

Comment: Ohhh It worked! Thank you so much!

Comment: Duplicate: [Error : Cannot read property 'map' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24706267/error-cannot-read-property-map-of-undefined)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your trying to map your users before the `get` request is done so it's undefined. Try something like

```
{
  users &&
    users.map((user) => (
      <UserCard
        key={user.id}
        userName={user.username}
        imageUrl="https://source.unsplash.com/random"
        userId={user.name}
      />
    ));
}
```

Comment: To add to this, it can be helpful to make the initial state of an Array type state to be an empty array. This means you can skip the `users &&`, as users will now never be undefined, the `map` will just see no items to map out. Once the data is loaded, the component will re-render with the new `users` array and map out your data.

Comment: Please check for dupes before posting an answer. This is a *very* common beginner's mistake that is posted all the time.

Comment: dude you saved me hours !!!! thank you

Answer (score 1):

You have a `loading` "state" to guard against attempting to render the items before any data has been fetched, but in `useAllUsers` you never actually declared the `loading` with a `useState`, so in the `UserManagement` it will always be false, leading it to attempt to render `users` before they are ready.

To fix, you can add the missing loading useState, and I also advise to put an empty array as the initial value of an array type state like so:

```js
const [users, setUsers] = useState<Array<User>>([])
```

Comment: Please check for dupes before posting an answer. This is a *very* common beginner's mistake that is posted all the time.